# Hippo CMS: add google tag manager code

Tags: google-tag-manager, hippocms

I wan't to add a tag manager tracking code to a site created in Hippo CMS but I can't find how to do this. I do find an explanation to add an analytics tracking code but that seems very specific to analytics.

Thanks,

Valerie

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert of google tag manager but I believe it is about javascript code you have to add somewhere in your templates (jsp or freemarker). Hippo has support for headcontributions to properly manage javascript/css from hippo components, read [1] for more details.

[1] https://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/web-application/head-contributions.html